# Was Jesus born in the house according to Matthew 2?

Tags: matthew, luke

(KJV) Matthew 2:10

> 10 When they saw the star, they rejoiced with exceeding great joy.   11 And when they were come into the ***house***, they saw the young child with Mary his mother, and fell down, and worshipped him:  and when they had opened their treasures, they presented unto him gifts;  gold, and frankincense, and myrrh.

But according to Luke  he was born in the stable

(KJV) Luke 2:6

> 6 And so it was, that, while they were there, the days were accomplished that she should be delivered.   7 And she brought forth her firstborn son, and ***wrapped*** him in swaddling clothes, and laid him in a manger;  because there was no room for them in the inn.

Where was Jesus born?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luke recounts the immediate circumstances of Jesus' birth, after the angelic host appeared to the shepherds in the fields.

Matthew's account of the so-called Magi bringing their gifts to Jesus occurs two years later. We know that from the fact that Herod enquires of them what time the star appeared to them, that is, when they were still in their own country, Matthew 2:7 :

> Then Herod, when he had privily called the wise men, inquired of them diligently what time the star appeared.

This is why he slaughtered all children under two years old.

So the Magi reached Bethlehem two years after the birth of Jesus Christ, a remarkable journey which indicates how far eastwards they must have travelled from - maybe India or Tibet or China. Who knows ?

Therefore the child Jesus was no longer in a manger but in a house.